# Take a sub string from a string from the end of the string to the first dot in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want take a sub string from a string from the end of the string to the first dot in Excel.

From:

```
de.hybris.platform.jdbcwrapper.PreparedStatementImpl
de.hybris.platform.persistence.GenericBMPBean$FindByPKListFinderResult
de.hybris.platform.cache.AbstractCacheUnit
de.hybris.platform.cache.AbstractCacheUnit
de.hybris.platform.cache.AbstractCacheUnit
```

The results are:

```
PreparedStatementImpl
GenericBMPBean$FindByPKListFinderResult
AbstractCacheUnit
AbstractCacheUnit
AbstractCacheUnit
```

Help me, thanks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your strings starts from A2 down to A6.
Write the formula 
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A2), ".", REPT(" ", 99)), 99)) in B2 and drag it down till end.

Comment: Okey. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression to find "anything until last dot" and replace those match by empty string.
The regular expression is  .*\.

.* means char for limited number

\. means character dot

.*\. means: please match anything for unlimited number followed by a dot